# Display issue in ios devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

I found my website is breaking in ios devices. But It is working fine in all desktop browsers and mobiles except in iphones. I took lot of time to debug this issue. The issue occurs due to the following reason.

(a) mobile browser (safari, chrome etc) in ios zoom when focus is given to a text input field and this breaks layout

(b) once the focus is lost, it is not regaining its initial state

I tested without binding any event to the input text. Still issue is same. What is so confusing is, this issue not coming in android or windows phones.

Did anyone face same issue? What is the best way to solve this issue?

As pointed out in the comments by @drnugent, most probably zooming by browser when focusing in input field in ios devices, is breaking the layout. Is disabling this feature recommended?

EDIT: This is a specific question pertaining to the issue faced in ios device while focusing on input field, and to my understanding, it does not violate any community guidelines. I do not know why somebody voted for closing this question.

Comment: Disclaimer: I did not vote to close. However, the reason they gave is _**"Needs debugging details"** If the question is a debugging question and lacks the necessary code to reproduce it, one should choose "needs debugging details"._ Post a minimal HTML page that reproduces the issue, you'll get more luck ;) Including your page's `<meta>` tags, which are very relevant here, I imagine

Comment: It's fairly trivial to disable the input zoom, here is one approach: https://medium.com/cssjunction/how-to-stop-zoom-in-on-input-focus-on-mobile-devices-835edcaa2ba4

Comment: thanks blex for the comment

Comment: @drnugent, i never new this concept. now i got a start, thanks

Comment: Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @drnugent, it is working. But i am confused and was searching for best way to do this. font size setting is the best solution so far i got as pointed out in the article mentioned by you. Also i am confused, whether to do this only for ios devices or for all mobiles.

Comment: @drnugent, i am testing  in various devices and this zoom appears only in ios regardless of browser. So, should i make a fix only for iphones?

Comment: @Kiran it's up to you, there should be no difference on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable viewport zoom with the following code:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`